# Why Object can be null with Array.isArray(obj) check?

Tags: typescript

In the code example is below, TypeScript is points on `result[key].push(submenuKey);` that result can be `null`, but there is a check for `Array.isArray()`

Code snippet:

```
interface resultI {
    [key: string]: string | null | any[];
}
const result: resultI = {
    fookey: ['foo', 'bar']
};

const key = 'fookey';
const submenuKey = 'submenuKey';

if (Array.isArray(result[key])) {
    result[key].push(submenuKey);
}
```

How is this possible?

[Link to playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAihAzgVwDZgJLIDeAUMmcgNoDWEAngFzLphSgDmAuo86yG8gB9kIHNkHI4IWhQ4BuYgF9iCAPYhmqDDjCM0WXAQC8RUuRgqVNBpQDk5lTYA0yGwCM4UGx0XzlajVbIxnYWVjbyqupgTJiuALYQIgDSdEEuWPGJmCm04cTEwDDIABQAglBQcLQAdMDo5ZW0xXra1HQcAJQdJuSa+mBttBzVAA6Y6AAWxRkJyXQd8kpAA)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Array.isArray()` guards the result of `result[key]` expression. The second occurrence of `result[key]` is a different expression, and it isn't guarded (TS cannot figure out that it's guarded). As a workaround, you can save the result of `result[key]` to a variable, and guard the variable, for example:

```js
...
const arr = result[key];
if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    arr.push(submenuKey);
}
```

I think it's because the key is a variable, in case of a static key, guard works well, for example:

```js
if (Array.isArray(result['fookey'])) {
    result['fookey'].push(submenuKey); // no errors
}
```

Comment: It's considered [a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) that `result[key]` isn't guarded... or at least it's a design limitation (since the compiler would need to recognize that `key` is the same value in both expressions despite having a `string` type)